# Combining arrays in JS

Tags: javascript

If you have 2 arrays classical and pop:

```
classical=["Beethoven","Mozart","Tchaikovsky"];
pop=["Beatles","Corrs","Fleetwood Mac","Status Quo"];
```

Why is that when you set `all=classical+pop` it gives sets character in the array elements an individual character?

How do you correct this without retyping i.e. `all=["Beethoven","Mozart","Tchaikovsky","Beatles"...]`

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the Array class concat() method to combine them on a new variable:

```
var all = classical.concat(pop);
```

Answer (score 4):

`+` is first converting both arrays to string, and then adding the strings. For this you need to use `concat` method.

```
> classical=["Beethoven","Mozart","Tchaikovsky"];
["Beethoven", "Mozart", "Tchaikovsky"]
> pop=["Beatles","Corrs","Fleetwood Mac","Status Quo"];
["Beatles", "Corrs", "Fleetwood Mac", "Status Quo"]
> all = classical.concat(pop)
["Beethoven", "Mozart", "Tchaikovsky", "Beatles", "Corrs", "Fleetwood Mac", "Status Quo"]
```